# Can I use config file for key value pairs?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have several key value pairs or mapping value, like
Eg: Liquid Manufacturing -> Processing+Batching+Filling+Sealing

There are several such key value pairs. These values might change frequently.
Whats the best practice? Can I save them to XML based config files? or database?
Can I have them in a config file and read it into a dictionary and use it in my application?

Thank you for your inputs.

"When will they change? Can the user change them or is it changed when the application is installed? Is the setting per user or per application? Is the setting valid only for one machine or does the same setting apply to clients on several machines?"

User cannot change them. Setting  applies to entire application, all machines.

Comment: When will they change? Can the user change them or is it changed when the application is installed? Is the setting per user or per application? Is the setting valid only for one machine or does the same setting apply to clients on several machines?

Comment: You can do any of those things; it depends how you're going to be using them.  I'd suggest you edit your question and add some more details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use resource files for these kinds of things. They are still text-based files that can be changed on-the-fly without impacting the site in a global sense. Sometimes I load them into variables at the Application level in the global.asax, other times I get them as needed.

http://kumarnitesh.wordpress.com/2008/04/16/how-to-use-resource-file-in-c/
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekyft91f(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekyft91f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ztca10y(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ztca10y%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

EDIT: A reason I choose not to put these sorts of things in the web.config is that the web.config can grow large pretty quickly in an application of any size. With resource files, the settings can be split apart into groupings of your choosing so the updating of one particular batch of settings can't accidentally overwrite or harm any settings for the other areas. I still use web.config for global application settings, but for other settings that might be specific to a page or particular application piece, I keep those sequestered.

Comment: I think this is the best approach I can implement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `appSettings` of you web.config

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="myKey" value="myValue"/>
</appSettings>
```

Access the values in code with

```
string myValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use a simple database table although you can use `appSettings` section to store key/value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx

There is an option to save the config file as well so they are not static.

Comment: My DBA is being a pain behind. He wants me to define relationships on the DB.

Comment: @Ram - surely he must be aware that not every table in a database relates to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table with columns for KEY and VALUE and store it there.Then write a wrapper class which will handle the transactions to this table(CREATE/READ/UPDATE/DELETE)

You can have "CREATED_BY","CREATED_DATE",MODIFIED_BY","MODIFIED_DATE" columns too,if you want to keep track of who changes the configuration settings and when(If you have a screen where users/admin can change these settings).

Having these in web.config brings a problem.Whenever you update the web.config,the session will be lost.It will restart the application.

Comment: "Having these in web.config brings a problem.Whenever you update the web.config,the session will be lost.It will restart the application." @Shyju  - Does this apply to resource files too?

Answer (score -1):

Windows registry is perfect for that.